# JavaScript Run full A href command

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website where there is a side menu filled with links. On top of that are some Next and Prev buttons for the user to switch between the menus of links.

I want to change this so that the menu will automatically change after x amount of time.

I thought something like this would do it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function delayer(){
 window.location = "http://www.google.com" }
 </script>
</head>

<body  onLoad="setTimeout('delayer()', 1000)">
</body>

</html>
```

Basically, instead of opening google, I want the page to run the "Next" button which is represented by:

```
<div class="navBtns mar9 s3">

<a href="#" class="prev"><span></span></a>
<a href="#" class="next"><span></span></a>

</div>
```

Any idea on how to do this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#" class="prev"><span></span></a>
```

This hyperlink does nothing by itself.  Somewhere on the site, there is a javascript function bound to the click event of this link.  You need to either trigger a click event on the link, or call the javascript directly.

Without seeing the rest of the javascript / knowing what frameworks are in use on the page, it's impossible to give a more precise answer.

-- EDIT --

Based on your comment, you may be able to do something along these lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#page_HOME .slider .next').click();
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

As long as those hyperlinks are contained inside the slider element, the above code will trigger a change in your side menu after 1000 milliseconds

Comment: How do I reply to your post? I only see comment?

Comment: You are right in that it does activate more JavaScript. Here is what it activates:  if ($('#page_HOME .slider').length) {
        $('#page_HOME .slider').cycle({
            fx: 'scrollHorz',
            speed: 600,
      timeout: 0,
            next: '.s3 .next',
      prev: '.s3 .prev',               
      easing: 'easeOutCubic',
      cleartypeNoBg: true ,
            rev:0,
            startingSlide: 0,
            wrap: true
    })};

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to "click" the next button, then you can do that programatically with JS.

```
var nextbutton = document.getElementsByClassName('next');
nextbutton.click();
```

Getting element by class like that only works on post-IE8 browsers.

Comment: How would I go about adding this to my page?

Comment: Plop that code directly in the delayer() function, for example, and it will be called when the redirect to google is occuring. All you need to do is add a href to the anchor element for it to do anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could find the HREF of the link you want based on the class name of the link, using plain old JS.

```js
window.location = document.querySelector(<link class name>).getAttribute("href");
```

This will redirect the browser to whatever the `href` attribute is set to.

If you wanted to keep a function like you have, you could use this:

```js
function delay(link, time) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location = document.querySelector("." + linkClass).getAttribute("href");
    }, time);
}
```

Then to use it, just say:

```
delay("next", 5000); // go to the href of the link with the class "next" after 5 seconds.
```